# Css breakpoint responsive rule

Tags: html, css, responsive, breakpoints

I'm using SASS to create CSS and responsiveness. I made a desktop version first and now I'm trying to make it responsive for a smaller screen.

And the rule of responsive desktop first is use breakpoint - 1px.

For screen under 1024, I set
`@media screen and (maw-width:1023px)`

And in the Chrome responsive dev tool, I must reduce the width to `1022px`, the CSS responsive is applied [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2IFs.png). Honestly, I think it should be applied since `1023px`

So I make a test, I change the number `1023px` become `1024px` `@media screen and (maw-width:1024px)`,
and the chrome dev tool apply this responsive CSS exactly at 1024px?

My problem is why there is this different? `breakpoint = 1023px`, it applies at 1022px screen, and `breakponint = 1024px`, it applies at 1024px? Could I have wrong knowledge about this or something wrong in my code?

Comment: You should go with the mobile-first approach which makes the responsiveness very easy. First design for mobile then go for tab and then finally for Desktop. Try once.

Comment: I'm practicing translate from pfd design to html css so I only have desktop template

Comment: You wrote `maw-width:1023px` both times you mention it. Is that really in the code? Should be `max-width:1023px`.